# How to get a rigid body to rotate?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I would like to get a cube to rotate in a scene as seen in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/Xel2fjW.gifv). Is there any way to do this without animation?

Comment: Could you use animation nodes? Of course, unless procedural animation is your thing it might be more difficult than just animating it.

Answer (score 1):

**It's really very easy to do this, Just follow these steps:**

[image: Set Blender engine mode to physics]

[image: Rigidbody setup for Cube]

[image: Goto Game Logics]

[image: Add logic bricks]

In addition to this if you want to add a force in the forward axis, then add a linear velocity or force in that axis.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way that I know of to do that without animation. But, that would be very simple to do. You can simply add your cube, press "i" and press lokrot scale, then chose another frame rotate it and do lokrot again.